# Unexpected behaviour when uploading multiple files using multipart/form-data media type in .NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, multipartform-data, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using .NET core 3.1 in my project where I have a situation to upload multiple files. Below is my model:

```
public class ProductImageDetailsDto
{
    [Display(Name = "product image")]
    [AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".jpg", ".png" })]
    public IFormFile ProductImage { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my WebAPI, in which I am accepting `List<ProductImageDetailsDto>` as a parameter:

```
    [HttpPut("UpdateProductImagesByProductId/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProdutImagesByProductId(Guid id, [FromForm] List<ProductImageDetailsDto> productImages)
    {
        ApiResponseModel<string> apiResponse = await _productDetailServices.UpdateProductImagesByProductIdAsync(id, productImages, new Guid(UserId));
        return Ok(apiResponse);
    }
```

When I pass data from postman or swagger, nothing is being received on the API side and `productImages` parameter has `count = 0`. I am passing the data from the postman like this:

```
productImages[0].ProductImage :  file
productImages[1].ProductImage :  file1
```

But if I modify my `ProductImageDetailsDto` class and add more field let's say IsDefault like below:

```
public class ProductImageDetailsDto
{
    [Display(Name = "product image")]
    [AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".jpg", ".png" })]
    public IFormFile ProductImage { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

And if I pass data from postman like this:

```
productImages[0].ProductImage :  file
productImages[0].IsDefault:      false
productImages[1].ProductImage :  file1
productImages[1].IsDefault:      true
```

everything seems to be working fine and I am receiving data i.e both ProductImage and IsDefault on the API side.

So what's the issue if I keep only `IFormFile` field in `ProductImageDetailsDto`. Is there anything I am missing or doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Note: I don't want to take `List<IFormFile>` or `IFormFileCollection` as parameter type in API as I want to validate the images using custom validator `[AllowedExtension]`, that's why I have created `IFormFile` property inside the Model and accepting `List<ProductImageDetailsDto>` as a parameter.

Comment: Hi @Sunny,How did you design `AllowedExtensions` attribute?If I do not use such attribute I could receive data by using what you did in postman.Please share your `AllowedExtensions` code and screenshot about how did you use postman(share what is your request header and form data).

Comment: Also,could you please share your Startup.cs,did you use asp.net core web api?And what is your controller?Does the controller decorated with [ApiController]?Please share controller more detailed.

Comment: @Rena I guess there is no issue with AllowedExtensions as I tried to comment It out but it didn't work. And Yes I am using .NET Core Web API template and controller is decorated with  [ApiController].

Comment: Hi @Sunny,Did you mind sharing your Starup.cs to us?

Comment: @Rena The issue is something weird. If I take one more field in ProductImageDetailsDto, let's say IsDefault as bool field, and if I pass it like productImages[0].IsDefault:  false along with ProductImage param, then everything is working fine. But if I pass only productImages[0].ProductImage, then I am not getting anything in the API.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like below if you want to pass only `productImages[0].ProductImage`,remove `[ApiController]` and `[FromForm]`:

```
// [ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{     
    [HttpPut("UpdateProductImagesByProductId/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProdutImagesByProductId(Guid id, List<ProductImageDetailsDto> productImages)
    {

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to maintain `[ApiController]` and custom validation,add the custom attribute in the action and remove `[FromForm]` like below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProdutImagesByProductId(Guid id,[AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".jpg", ".png"})] List<IFormFile> files)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Can you please explain why should I remove [ApiController] and [FromForm]

Comment: It seems to be by design.I raise a github issue and waiting for PG's explanation.You could follow:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28273 .And if my workaround works for you.Could you please accept as answer.

Comment: I can't remove [ApiController] as there are other APIs as well in the same controller. I tried removing  [ApiController] but it didn't work. So you were able to generate my issue. right?

Comment: and thanks for raising the issue on github.

Comment: Yes,I could reproduce the same issue with you.`I tried removing [ApiController] but it didn't work.`.So did you also remove  [FromForm]?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I can't remove [ApiController] so I tried removing [FromForm] but it didn't work. Removing [ApiController] would not be a solution for me.

Comment: Ok.Maybe need to custom model binding.I will still research.But I think remove both [ApiController] and [FromForm] is the fastest way.I think you could create a new controller and put your method in it.

Comment: fastest way would be to have IFormCollection as a datatype of the parameter in API. That will only bypass the validation and can write business logic for the same inside the service.

Comment: yes. That's a good workaround. Though waiting for the aspnetcore team to reply. Please update the answer once you got the reply from aspnetcore team on Github issue.